# get key and value from array in php

Tags: php

using this array data:

```
$tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
        );
```

i want to be able to get the key and value, i tried

```
$tokens["day"];
```

but its not returning anything.

how can i get each item but not inside a loop? (foreach for example)

Comment: This is basic 101 arrays: `$tokens[1]` to access second and `$keys = array_keys($tokens);` to get an array of the keys, to access `$keys[0] for 31536000`

Comment: @Rizier123, actually you are wrong, calling `$tokens[0]` would yield the result of `string "year"`, the OP's array is inverted the wrong way around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access the key, via a known value, then you can simply flip the array with `array_flip`:

```
$flipped = array_flip($tokens);

echo $flipped['day']; //86400
```

Or, just create the array in the correct manner in the first place if you have access to the code that does so:

```
$tokens = array (
    'year'   => 31536000,
    'month'  => 2592000,
    'week'   => 604800,
    'day'    => 86400,
    'hour'   => 3600,
    'minute' => 60,
    'second' => 1
    );
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution that exists when an array is inverted!

Answer (score 10):

That's because `day` is the *value*, not the key.

`$tokens["86400"]` is equal to `day`.

You need to rearrange your array so that `'day' => 86400`, not the other way around!

An easy way to do this is using [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$key = array_search('day', $tokens);` You can get a index using value

`$tokens["day"];`  this will not returning any thing because 'day' is not index it is a value

You can get value of array using index
like
`$token['86400']`  this will return value **"day"**

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several options here.

1. You can use a foreach loop
2. You can use array search func passing the value and getting the key.
3. You can use a for loop (but it's kinda tuff)

Let's start with the first one, the simplest:

```
$my_array = [
2334325 => "val_1",
4354524 => "val_2",
3213144 => "val_3",
3232412 => "val_4"
];

#here we use a "trick" for the foreach loop
foreach($my_array as $key => $val)
{
    echo "Key: $key <br/>Value: $val <br/><br/>";
}
```

With this loop you can access in a quick way keys and values.

Let's take a look to the second method, even if i suggest you to use the first one:

```
$my_array = [
2334325 => "val_1",
4354524 => "val_2",
3213144 => "val_3",
3232412 => "val_4"
];

#let's make it dynamic. We create a function

function arrSrc($arg)
{
    #we declare a index
    $index;

    #we search the index by given value
    $index = array_search($arg);

    return $index;
}

echo arrSrc("val_1");
```

For the rest i don't want to go too deep even with the for loop. But i think that this can help you.

-Keep on hacking!

Answer (score 0):

You must interchange the array key and values using `array_flip`.
It is the easy way to get the answer.

```
$flipped_array = array_flip($tokens);
echo $flipped_array['day'];
```

Result is:
86400

Answer (score 0):

There are so many solutions already available, so i am adding my solution here. You can also use `array_keys()` as:

```
$tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
        );

$arrayKeys = array_keys($tokens);
$requiredVal = $tokens[$arrayKeys[3]];
echo $requiredVal; // result "day"
```

**Explanation:**

Use `array_keys` function for getting keys and than use in original array as 
`$tokens[$arrayKeys[3]]` because this index have your required value (**day**).